# SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Unmarshalling Error:

Tags: android, android-webservice

I am calling web service using Soap in Android. But i am getting an error

> SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://ws.service.tbank.co.th/", local:"arg0"). Expected elements are <{}arg0> ' faultactor: 'null' detail: null .

Wsdl File :

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.service.tbank.co.th/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="BillPaymentValidate" targetNamespace="http://ws.service.tbank.co.th/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://ws.service.tbank.co.th/" targetNamespace="http://ws.service.tbank.co.th/" version="1.0">
<xs:element name="validateRef1" type="tns:validateRef1"/>
<xs:element name="validateRef1Response" type="tns:validateRef1Response"/>
<xs:complexType name="validateRef1">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="validateRef1Response">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="return" type="xs:boolean"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="validateRef1">
<wsdl:part element="tns:validateRef1" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="validateRef1Response">
<wsdl:part element="tns:validateRef1Response" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="BillPaymentValidateImpl">
<wsdl:operation name="validateRef1">
<wsdl:input message="tns:validateRef1" name="validateRef1"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:validateRef1Response" name="validateRef1Response"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BillPaymentValidateSoapBinding" type="tns:BillPaymentValidateImpl">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="validateRef1">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="validateRef1">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="validateRef1Response">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="BillPaymentValidate">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:BillPaymentValidateSoapBinding" name="BillPaymentValidateImplPort">
<soap:address location="http://TB58DBWHH3201P:8080/TbankWSService/BillPaymentValidate"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>

SOAP request
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.service.tbank.co.th/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:validateRef1>
         <arg0>1234567890</arg0>
      </ws:validateRef1>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Example: SOAP response
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:validateRef1Response xmlns:ns2="http://ws.service.tbank.co.th/">
         <return>true</return>
      </ns2:validateRef1Response>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

My code :

public class Soap {

    public boolean GetValidate(String billReference) {
        String URL = "http://192.168.1.101:8080/TbankWSService/BillPaymentValidate?WSDL";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.service.tbank.co.th/";
        String METHOD = "validateRef1";
        String SOAP_ACTION = "";
        boolean validation = false;
        String result;

        //Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
        PropertyInfo PI = new PropertyInfo();
        PI.setName("arg0");
        PI.setValue(billReference);
        PI.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(PI);
        //Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =
                new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        //Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        Log.d("Aamir","calling URL");

        androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
        try {
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Log.d("Aamir","Aamir");
            // Get the response
             SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            //SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            Log.d("Aamir","Response :"+response);

            // Assign it to  boolean variable variable
            validation = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
            Log.d("Aamir", "Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return validation;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
03-22 12:47:05.613  2466  2490 W System.err: SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://ws.service.tbank.co.th/", local:"arg0"). Expected elements are <{}arg0> ' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

03-22 12:47:05.614  2466  2490 W System.err:    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:137)

03-22 12:47:05.614  2466  2490 W System.err:    at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)

03-22 12:47:05.614  2466  2490 W System.err:    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129)

03-22 12:47:05.614  2466  2490 W System.err:    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.parseResponse(HttpTransportSE.java:301)

03-22 12:47:05.614  2466  2490 W System.err:    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:274)

03-22 12:47:05.614  2466  2490 W System.err:    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)

03-22 12:47:05.614  2466  2490 W System.err:    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)

03-22 12:47:05.614  2466  2490 W System.err:    at com.example.myapp.Soap.GetValidate(Soap.java:45)

03-22 12:47:05.614  2466  2490 W System.err:    at com.example.myapp.MyActivity$AsyncCallSoap.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:44)
```

Comment: Please some body help to solve this error.. please

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution . This is i am getting because i am getting wrong request .. Need to check request.  you can do it by using Log.d(TAG,"requestdump:"+androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
 Log.d(TAG,"responseDump:"+androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

AND CHECK THE namespace . you may need to play with namespace which is happened in my case.